# Can't change colour of image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I've png images in assets I've set `Render As Template` image. Following is the code. Why doesn't it set the image to be white? How to fix it?

```
@IBOutlet weak var iconImageView: UIImageView!

iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ico")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
iconImageView.tintColor = .white
```

Comment: It should work. I tried your code and it's working for me. You can check image name in asset and code.

Comment: I think something is wrong with image itself not sure what.

Comment: Can you please send me image? I can check and let you know.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Df8PgIH

Comment: Just posted my answer. please try that. The image is having transparency that's why color will not be visible properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine and it's working perfectly. The only problem is the image is having transparency that's why color is not visible properly.

Answer (score 0):

it should work .  try this, almost same.

```
extension UIImageView {
func setImageColor(color: UIColor) {
    let templateImage = self.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
    self.image = templateImage
    self.tintColor = color
}
```

}